# How does the electronic structure Hamiltonian scales with basis sets and the number electrons?

Tags: quantum-chemistry, computational-chemistry, electronic-configuration, basis-set

Given a chemical system with $N$ electrons and a basis set $S  = \{\phi_i\}$ with $K$ basis functions. If one to discretize the Hamiltonian with this basis sets, what is the dimension?

The electronic structure problem $H|\psi\rangle = E|\psi\rangle$ is usually said to be hard because it scales badly. I want to understand explicitly how does the dimension of $H$ scale in term of the problem size (the electrons and basis set in consideration)?

If someone can give me the detail to this exponential scaling (?) and maybe an explicit example then it would be greatly appreciated, but I would be happy to get any helpful information/pointer on this.

Comment: Well, to start with the obvious, with $K$ basis functions your wavefunction is going to be a $K \times 1$ column vector, and the Hamiltonian is going to be a $K \times K$ matrix. What scaling are you asking about, though? The word scaling on its own seems a bit vague to me. There is not only the size of the problem, but also the question of how long it takes to solve a problem of a given size (i.e. diagonalise $H$). Are you specifically asking about the relationship between $K$ and the number of atoms / number of electrons?

Comment: @orthocresol Sorry for not being detail in the question. Diagonalizing H can be done in $O(N^3)$ and potentially down to around $O(N^{2.37})$, so what make this problem hard must be the fact that $H$ scales exponentially with respect to the number of electrons, which in turn $K$ must be scales exponentially as well. Since as you mentioned, with $K$ basis function, the dim of $H$ is $K \times K$. So yes, what is the relationship between $K$ and the number of atoms or electrons?

Comment: I recommend to [edit] the question to include the details from your comment.